# Comparitive Operators

Tags: javascript, loops, operators, conditional-statements

I'm a newbie to JS.
I have to write a function containing ( loop, Conditional statement & operator) that...

1. Asks 3 questions - that is as far as I got
2. Gives two attempts to answer correctly
3. Keeps a total of correct answers
4. Displays that total to screen

I have only got this far as shown below. I am totally stuck now. Help please!

```
function capitalCity()

{

    var answer1 = prompt("What is the capital of France?","");
    var answer2 = prompt("what is the capital of Scotland?","");
    var answer3 = prompt("what is the capital of Spain?","");



    if ( answer1 == "Paris" && answer2 == "Edinburgh" && answer3 == "Madrid")
    {
    alert("You have passed!");
    }

    else if ( answer1 != "Paris" || answer2 != "Edinburgh" || answer3 != "Madrid")
    {
    alert("Have another go!");
    capitalCity();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question?  Does this work?  Not work?  What *exactly* are you stuck on?

Comment: It does not keep track or run twice

Comment: Are you expecting someone to do something for you without knowing how you are stuck? Be more specific.

Comment: For #2, you'll need some sort of `loop` construct (`while` or `do`)..  Your `if` statement won't really work for adding up the score, you'll have to judge each answer individually.  Re-think your approach here.

Comment: People, give the noob a fighting chance. It is obvious where he go stuck and you were all beginners once. At least he posted code

Comment: To display to page, have a look at `document.getElementById("somecontainerID").innerHTML` instead of alert

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution to your problem. You can use as many questions as you want:

```
function askQuestions(secondTime) {
    var questionsAndAnswers = [
        ["What is the capital of France?",   "Paris"], 
        ["what is the capital of Scotland?", "Edinburgh"], 
        ["what is the capital of Spain?",    "Madrid"]
    ];
    var correctAnswers = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < questionsAndAnswers.length; i++) {
        var questionAndAnswer = questionsAndAnswers[i],
            answer = prompt(questionAndAnswer[0], "");

        if(answer.toLowerCase() === questionAndAnswer[1].toLowerCase()) {
            correctAnswers++;
        }
    }

    var ratio = Math.round(correctAnswers/questionsAndAnswers.length*100);
    alert(ratio + "% questions are correct");

    if(!secondTime && ratio < 100) {
        askQuestions(true);
    }
}

askQuestions();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to only run twice, make a counter variable outside of the loop. Here's how it'd look.

```
var count = 0;

function capitalCity()
{
    if(count >= 2){
    count = 0;
    alert('you failed...');
    return;
    }
    var answer1 = prompt("What is the capital of France?","");
    var answer2 = prompt("what is the capital of Scotland?","");
    var answer3 = prompt("what is the capital of Spain?","");



    if ( answer1 == "Paris" && answer2 == "Edinburgh" && answer3 == "Madrid")
    {
    alert("You have passed!");
    count = 0;
    }

    else if ( answer1 != "Paris" || answer2 != "Edinburgh" || answer3 != "Madrid")
    {
    alert("Have another go!");
    count++;
    capitalCity();
    }
}
```

Comment: alert("You have passed!"); return; and you do not mean `if (count <=2)`

Comment: You're right. Typo :/ I meant `count>=2`. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this solution first as it looks the closest to my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I missed the two-attempts criteria.

Here's an updated solution [[demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/MMBWV/1/):

```
function capitalCity() {
    var countryCapitals = {
        France: 'Paris',
        Scotland: 'Edinburgh',
        Spain: 'Madrid'
    };

    var correctAnswersCount = 0;

    for (var country in countryCapitals) {
        var question = 'What is the capital of ' + country + '?',
            answer = countryCapitals[country];

        if (prompt(question) == answer || prompt('Try again:\n' + question) == answer) {
            correctAnswersCount++;
        }
    }

    alert('Number of correct answers: ' + correctAnswersCount);
}

capitalCity();
```

Note that the use of prompts/alerts makes for a rather terrible UI, but it keeps the answer simple as you were using them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Trivia(attempts, attempt) {
    var questions = [],
        correct = 0;
        attempt = attempt || 0;
    questions.push({
        question: 'What is the capital of France?',
        answer : 'Paris',
    });
    questions.push({
        question: 'What is the capital of Scotland?',
        answer : 'Edinburgh',
    });
    questions.push({
        question: 'What is the capital of Spain?',
        answer : 'Madrid',
    });
    for (var i in questions) {
        var answer = prompt(questions[i].question);
        if (answer.toLowerCase() == questions[i].answer.toLowerCase()) {
            correct++;
        }
    }
    if (correct < questions.length) {
        if (attempt >= attempts - 1) {
            alert('Sorry, u suck too much');
            return;
        }
        alert('U suck, retry');
        Trivia(attempts, attempt+1);
    } else {
        alert('Good Job!');
    }
}
Trivia(3);
//call trivia with 3 max tries
```